# PHP & MySql | Add Extra DIV If The Number Of Sql Rows Exceeds A Given Number

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have the following PHP function which will list the users from a MySql table and will print the HTML code as you can see:

```
//List All Users From The Database Table In An Array
public function listUsersInArray() {
    $sql = "SELECT username FROM user";
    $users = array();
    if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->bind_result($usrn);
        $stmt->execute();

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $stmt->bind_result($usrn);
            $users[] = $usrn;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return $users;
    }
        else {
            $error = true;
            $message['error'] = true;
            $message['message'] = "The Users Could Not Stored In Array";
            return json_encode($message);       
        }
}

//Build A Form In Order To Print Out The Users For Deleting
private function createForm($id) {
    $form = array(  '<form name="delete-user" id="'.$id.'" class="delete-user" method="post" action="#">',
                        '<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'.$id.'" />',
                        '<fieldset class="user-wrapper">',
                            '<label for="user" class="user-label">User</label>',
                            '<input type="text" name="user" class="user" value="'.$id.'" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" />',
                        '</fieldset>',
                        '<fieldset class="delete-wrapper">',
                            '<button type="submit" name="delete" class="delete">Delete</button>',
                        '</fieldset>',
                    '</form>' 
            );
    $form = implode("",$form);
    return  $form;                  
}

//List All Users From Array As Forms For Deleting
public function listUsersForDelete() {
    $users = $this->listUsersInArray();     
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($users) ; $i++) {
        while((sizeof($users) <= ($i % 7 == 0 || $i == 0))) {
        echo $this->createForm($users[$i]);
        $i++;
    }
    }   
}
```

And now I just have to figure out how to add a wrap the all the forms in a div if the forms are more than 7 and do that each time I encounter a multiple of 7.

For example, if I have 9 forms, wrap the first 7 in a div but also wrap the rest in another div, and if I have 16 forms, wrap the first 7 in a div, the next 7 in a div and the rest of 2 in another div, and so on ...

Comment: Yes, you will want to investigate the *[modulus operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)*.

Comment: OK. I'll study that, I guess that's for the second part of what I asked, the multiple of the number. But how do I do what I asked on the above function ?

Comment: In theory, all you need to do is whenever you reach a multiple of 7, then output `</div><div>`.  You can arrange that into a function however you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You suggested code looks fine.  The only thing I would suggest is that you store the `<form>` code into a variable first instead of just copying and pasting it.  Copying and pasting is prone to a lot of errors, especially if you have to update the code later.

Comment: Well, I just came up with another idea. I think it will get me faster to what I want. Look at the new code I edit in the question and tell me what do you think ? Wouldn't it be easier if I had all the users listed in an array and then see if the array length is greater than 7 and do what I want ?

Comment: Yes, that's another way of doing it.  If you have all the users in an array, it's even easier because you can split it into chunks with `array_chunk`.

Comment: So, I keep trying to find the logic I want and asked about, I came up with this but I'm not sure if I am correct, actually I am convinced that I'm wrong :) `$i = 0;
  while(($i < sizeof($users)) || (sizeof($users) <= ($i % 7 == 0 || $i == 0))) {
   echo $this->createForm($users[$i]);
   $i++;
  }` Am I wrong ?

Comment: Let me explain again what I want to achieve, for example, if I have 9 forms, wrap the first 7 in a div but also wrap the rest in another div, and if I have 16 forms, wrap the first 7 in a div, the next 7 in a div and the rest of 2 in another div, and so on ... , now I have reached this point with the code, I think now I need the logic to do what I need. I edited again my question with the last changes to the code.

Answer (score -1):

Modulus would work but you may want to use an array to easily enclose the forms in divs if it's greater then 7 results.

Try adapting this script as it displays results in a table grid view.

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
$number_of_thumbs_in_row = 2;
$result = mysql_query("");
$nr = mysql_num_rows($result);
if (empty($nr)) {
    $result_final = "\t<tr><td></td></tr>\n";
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $result_array[] = "<tr>your data</tr>";        
    }
    $result_final = "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($result_array as $thumbnail_link) {
        if ($counter == $number_of_thumbs_in_row) {
            $counter = 1;
            $result_final .= "\n</tr>\n<tr>\n";
        } else
            $counter++;
        $result_final .= "\t<td>" . $thumbnail_link . "</td>\n";
    }
    if ($counter) {
        if ($number_of_photos_in_row - $counter)
            $result_final .= "\t<td colspan='" . ($number_of_photos_in_row - $counter) .
                "'>&nbsp;</td>\n";
    }
    $result_final .= "</tr>";
}
echo $result_final;
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: -1 Please stop using the ancient `mysql_*` functions and, if it is too hard for you, at least stop recommending them to others.

Comment: Well, I have that forms for a reason, there would be no point in using  table. Also, tables are something that I never use. Anyway, I don't use that kind of mysql_ functions, all of my code is done as the function I stated in the question. And I don't have any photo in my table, I have users, for a login system. Thank you anyway @xkrv